# How do I swap two blocks with /clone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a map in which you switch blocks around, but depending on the order you do it, I can't use `/setblock` or else it might set the wrong block. I know I can use `/clone` to clone one block and place it in another spot, but is it possible to do this to two blocks at the same time to switch their positions?

Comment: I don't think so, but you might be able to have a spot designated for the shift? Like a empty space you can move the block to temporarily.

Comment: Okay, I'll post as an answer when I have time so you can accept it.

Comment: Posted an answer, you can accept now. Thanks to @Nick for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a temporary spot.

Designate a certain space (really anywhere, preferably underground in a spawn chunk) for the *swap space*. Then:

1. `/clone` block A into the swap space.
2. Clone block B into the spot where A was.
3. Clone A into the spot where B was at the start.

Quick diagram (with clearing the swap space at the end)

```
_ A B
A A B
A B B
A B A
_ B A
```

Note: I say underground in a spawn chunk for 2 reasons:

- Underground hopefully won't let anybody near it (idk if entities in the spot will break `/clone`.
- If you don't place it in a loaded chunk, then it will have to load the chunk every time you move the block (causing lag). The spawn chunks are already loaded (permanently), so this won't cause a problem.